# Can't rsync into subfolder, or even ssh at this point

Tags: ssh

I need to rsync log files like this:

```
 rsync --progress -rvze ssh name@host:/path/to/folder/*.log
```

When I run this command though, I get an error:

```
rsync: getcwd(): No such file or directory (2)
```

No such file or directory? That's odd. So I try to ssh directly:

```
ssh name@host
```

it prompts to enter my name, I do, then I type

```
cd /path/to/folder
```

which works fine (log files are present).

I double checked my ssh keys, everything seems to be in order there, but for some reason I can't ssh into a subfolder on this host, so there's no way I can get rsync working correctly.

EDIT:

Running the identical rsync command on my Mac, it works fine. Running it in my ubuntu EC2 instance is still failing.

Comment: `ssh name@host:/path/to/folder/`: ssh doesn't expect or accept a folder name here. It's taking everything after the '@' as a hostname, including the colon and the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure there are any log files at all? If not this command will fail with the 'No such file or directory'

Rather use:

```
rsync --progress --include='*.log' -rvze ssh name@host: /path/to/folder/ local_folder
```

The 'direct' ssh syntax you use in your second test is not supported:

```
ssh name@host:/path/to/folder/
```

because it will use `host:/path/to/folder/` as the hostname.

Comment: I am sure the log files are there. In fact when I run the identical command from my mac, it rsyncs just fine.